# Cisco switch SVI MAC address strange problem

Tags: vlan, mac

I am having the SVI MAC address problem on my switch (3850)  The MAC address of the SVI (VLAN2) is currently conflicting with another switch.  Why did this switch decide to use 7018.xxx.xxx  MAC address when the base MAC is totally different. I need to change the SVI MAC address but not sure I can do this.  Please advise. Thank you.

See snippet:

```
SWITCH1#sh ver | i Base
Base Ethernet MAC Address          : d4:ad:71:f8:47:00
SWITCH1#sh int vlan 2
Vlan2 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 7018.a7a6.d8f7 (bia 7018.a7a6.d8f7)

interface Vlan2
 ip address 10.100.241.251 255.255.255.0



SWITCH2#sh ver | i Base
Base Ethernet MAC Address          : 70:18:a7:a6:d8:80
SWITCH2#sh int vlan2
Vlan2 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Ethernet SVI, address is 7018.a7a6.d8f7 (bia 7018.a7a6.d8f7)

interface Vlan2
 ip address 10.100.241.58 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Run the same commands on the other switch and post those too.

Comment: Also, show us the SVI configurations.

Comment: See the snippets from SWITCH1 and SWITCH2

Comment: We need the entire configurations. It’s inconceivable that bia addresses would be duplicated. There must be something else going on.

Comment: Either the MAC has been directly entered in the configuration, or someone has been messing with the ROM internals.

Comment: BIA is hardware, is this grey-market?